# Store and read HTML in database with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I want to allow HTML in a comment box (eventually use tinymce or something like that), store it in an MSSQL database, and then read it back to a page where the field is rendered in a tabl cell.

It all works fine with the storing of the HTML after I fixed the validation problem on the action method. But when read back from the database, it renders the text with the HTML tags visible, instead of formatted HTML. I.e. if I look at the HTML source code in the table, its like this:

```
        <td> 
            &lt;p&gt;Testing HTML&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Hope it works&lt;/p&gt;
        </td>
```

So how do I render it as formatted text? When I did this to test out the validation, I just wrote in the tags in the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Professional ASP.NET MVC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470643188) provides this explanation about the differences in "code nuggets":

> When we look at the Details.aspx
>   template more closely, we’ll find
>   that it contains static HTML as well
>   as embedded rendering code. <% %> code
>   nuggets execute code when the View
>   template renders, and <%: %> code
>   nuggets execute the code contained
>   within them and then render the result
>   to the output stream of the template.

Left out of this description is how a code nugget in a <%= %> works. Scott Guthrie describes the difference in his post [New <%: %> Syntax for HTML Encoding Output in ASP.NET 4 (and ASP.NET MVC 2)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx). Phil Haack discusses this in more detail in a series on HTML encoding blocks which starts with [Html Encoding Code Blocks With ASP.NET 4](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/25/html-encoding-code-nuggets.aspx).

What you've discovered is that <%= %> spits out raw HTML into the output stream while <%: %> does HTML encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You want to [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx)

To give the MSDN example

HttpUtility.HtmlDecode Method

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

   class MyNewClass
   {
      public static void Main()
      {
         String myString;
         Console.WriteLine("Enter a string having '&' or '\"'  in it: ");
         myString=Console.ReadLine();
         String myEncodedString;
         // Encode the string.
         myEncodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myString);
         Console.WriteLine("HTML Encoded string is "+myEncodedString);
         StringWriter myWriter = new StringWriter();
         // Decode the encoded string.
         HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myEncodedString, myWriter);
         Console.Write("Decoded string of the above encoded string is "+
                        myWriter.ToString());
      }
   }
```

Comment: Well, I already tried that, but it didn't work. But maybe I found the answer: I had used <%: item.Comment %> to write out the text in the view. I guess that : encodes it back, even though I used HtmlUtility.HtmlDecode in the controller. So if I changed to <%= item.Comment %> it seems to work.